# ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2'

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im trying to train a model using TensorFlow.

When running

```
python Tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet --pipeline_config_path=Tensorflow/workspace/models/my_ssd_mobnet/pipeline.config --num_train_steps=5000
```

I get this

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'model_lib_v2' from 'object_detection' (C:\Users\lais\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\object_detection\__init__.py)
```

This is my directory structure

```
+RealTimeDetection
  +Tensorflow
  +workspace
  +models
    +research
     +object_detection
       model_main_tf2.py
       model_lib_v2.py
```

The models folder is from https://github.com/tensorflow/models so I know its supposed to work

What I think why its not working is that, the model_main_tf2.py is trying to import from

> C:\Users\lais\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\object_detection\

and not from

> C:\Users\lais\Desktop\SP\CIOT\projects\RealTimeObjectDetection\Tensorflow\models\research\object_detection

How do I make the code look for the libraries in the models\research\object_detection instead?
Or is my theory wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using a relative import by starting the import with a "."